# SQL - Multi part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, join

I have to implement an existing SQL query into a procedure.

This is the query:

```
WITH path(pot, pat, CostCenterID) 
    AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(CAST(Position AS varchar(5)) + '.' AS varchar(30)) AS pos
        , CAST(' . ' AS varchar(30)) AS poi
        , CostCenterID
    FROM
        dbo.View_CostCenter_ActHierarchy AS c
    WHERE
        (ParentID = '          ') 
        AND (Scenario = (SELECT status FROM dbo.Help_Variables WHERE (id = 'actsce'))) 
        AND (Version =  (SELECT status FROM dbo.Help_Variables WHERE (id = 'actver')))

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CAST(p.pot + CAST(c.Position AS varchar(5)) + '.' AS varchar(30)) AS pos
        , CAST(p.pat + ' . ' AS varchar(30)) AS poi
        , c.CostCenterID
    FROM
        dbo.View_CostCenter_ActHierarchy AS c 
        INNER JOIN paths AS p ON c.ParentID = p.CostCenterID
    WHERE 
        (c.Scenario = (SELECT status FROM  dbo.Help_Variables WHERE (id = 'actsce'))) 
        AND (c.Version = (SELECT status FROM dbo.Help_Variables  WHERE (id = 'actver')))

)
```

It looks very good until the second `select-statement`. There I am getting errors for: `p.pot`, `p.pat`, `paths` and `p.CostCenterID`. The error is:

> the multi part identifier for ... could not be bound

Does anyone had any experience with that or give me some hints as I am new to SQL.
Your answers are very apreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you want the CTE to be called `paths` not `path`.

Comment: oh thank you its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you named your CTE **path**

```
WITH path(pot, pat, CostCenterID)
```

but in INNER JOIN you refer to it using **paths**

```
FROM
    dbo.View_CostCenter_ActHierarchy AS c 
    INNER JOIN paths AS p ON c.ParentID = p.CostCenterID
```